# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" when starting WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager

Tags: java, wso2

I've downloaded Version 1.0.0 of WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager
I followed the [Prerequisites](https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/Prerequisites) 
and
the [General Server Configurations](https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/General+Server+Configurations)

System Win 7 64bit 12GB RAM
JDK java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
JAVA_HOME is set to JDK Directory

if I execute:

```
<PRODUCT_HOME>\bin>wso2server.bat --run
```

I get following error:

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WSO2MO~1.0\bin\..
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WSO2MO~1.0\bin\..\repository\logs\heap-dump.h
prof ...
Heap dump file created [1077051686 bytes in 5.148 secs]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.
java:130)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractString
Builder.java:114)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:535
)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:322)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:363)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.processBundle
sInfoFile(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.perform(Dropi
nsBundleDeployer.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.invokeExtensions(Main.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:94)
    ... 6 more
```

I tried to raise heap size in `wso2server.bat` on line 161 up to `-Xms4000m` `XmX8000m`but then I get an error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit`

What can I do to get the Enterprise Mobility Server succesfully running?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497259/how-to-fix-requested-array-size-exceeds-vm-limit-error-in-java) any help?

Comment: sorry no positive results with these options  - `-Xmx6G -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -XX:+UseCompressedOops`
the exact result is `Requested array size exceeds VM limit`

Comment: Can you post your heap dump in WSO mailing list? We might be able to help you?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to raise heap size in wso2server.bat on line 161 up to
>   -Xms4000 XmX8000

You omitted the units - which defaults to kilobytes.  Try:

```
-Xms4g -Xmx8g
```

You might also try running with `-verbose:gc` and visualize the data with a tool like [HPjmeter](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=HPJMETER).  This will help you with sizing the heap appropriately.

Comment: Hi Amir, i tried to take a look with HPjmeter at heap file `heap-dump.hprof` and click on Estimate->Memory Leaks 
`Memory Leaks: Memory Leaks: bytes held
1074003964 char[]@700000858` shows up  
I'm new to the tool so if you want any other metrics please let me know.

Comment: that just means there is about 1 gig of Strings that you're keeping in memory.  If this answer or the others provided helped you, you should consider voting on them or accepting them.

Comment: till now no answer helps me to get the EMM-Server to run - and till now I can't vote on an answer ... missing reputation :-(

Comment: Amir can you post your heap dump in WSO mailing list? We might be able to help you.

Comment: @Dilshan, I'm not the person who ran into the issue - I'm someone who attempted to help the OP.

Comment: Ooops sorry messed up the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your `-Xms` and `-Xmx` options are way too low.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms) may be helpful.  The number after those options is not in KB or MB, it's in just B... Your JVM won't even run at 8000B.  Try increasing it to a reasonable number.

**Edit:** The prerequisites you linked states you need:

> ~ 512 MB heap size. This is generally sufficient to process typical SOAP messages but the requirements vary with larger message sizes and  the number of messages processed concurrently.

Comment: sorry I forgot the "m"   -Xms4048m -Xmx8048m

Comment: @hifi-dd, you forgot the 'm' on here or in the environment?

Comment: i added the forgotten 'm' everywhere, I can