# Requested array size exceeds VM limit in MLLib Random Forest

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using MLLib to train a random forest. It's working fine to depth 15, but if I use depth 20 I get

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

on the driver, from the collectAsMap operation in DecisionTree.scala, around line 642. It doesn't happen until a good hour into training. I'm using 50 trees on 36 slaves with maxMemoryInMB=250, but still get an error even if I use a driver memory of 240G.

Has anybody seen this error in this context before, and can advise on what might be triggering it?

Best, Luke

Comment: Perhaps using a 64-bit JVM and `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` solves the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497506/942774