# Pyspark java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Tags: python, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a Pyspark job:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client --driver-memory 150G --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 150G benchmark_script_1.py hdfs:///tmp/data/sample150k 128 hdfs:///tmp/output/sample150k | tee ~/output/sample150k.log
```

The job itself is pretty standard. It just grabs some files and counts them.:

```
print(str(datetime.now()) + " - Ingesting files...")
files = sc.wholeTextFiles(inputFileDir, partitions)
fileCount = files.count()
print(str(datetime.now()) + " - " + str(fileCount) + " files ingested")
```

The source folder contains ~150'000 files. It's about 35G without replication and 105G with replication. Fairly heavy but not insane.

Running the above gives the following stacktrace:

```
15/08/11 15:39:20 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 61.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 76, <NODE>): java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:794)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:833)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:897)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
        at org.spark-project.guava.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:207)
        at org.spark-project.guava.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:252)
        at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1617)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:205)
```

More information can be found in the offending executor logs:

```
15/08/11 12:28:18 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
15/08/11 12:28:18 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:350)
        at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:939)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:573)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:405)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1617)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:205)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/jars/spark-assembly-1.3.0-cdh5.4.2-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.2.jar/pyspark/daemon.py", line 162, in manager
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/jars/spark-assembly-1.3.0-cdh5.4.2-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.2.jar/pyspark/daemon.py", line 60, in worker
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/jars/spark-assembly-1.3.0-cdh5.4.2-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.2.jar/pyspark/worker.py", line 126, in main
    if read_int(infile) == SpecialLengths.END_OF_STREAM:
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/jars/spark-assembly-1.3.0-cdh5.4.2-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.2.jar/pyspark/serializers.py", line 528, in read_int
15/08/11 12:28:18 ERROR util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[stdout writer for python,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:350)
        at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:939)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:573)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:405)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1617)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:205)
    raise EOFError
EOFError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/jars/spark-assembly-1.3.0-cdh5.4.2-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.2.jar/pyspark/daemon.py", line 162, in manager
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/jars/spark-assembly-1.3.0-cdh5.4.2-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.2.jar/pyspark/daemon.py", line 60, in worker
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/jars/spark-assembly-1.3.0-cdh5.4.2-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.2.jar/pyspark/worker.py", line 126, in main
    if read_int(infile) == SpecialLengths.END_OF_STREAM:
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/jars/spark-assembly-1.3.0-cdh5.4.2-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.2.jar/pyspark/serializers.py", line 528, in read_int
15/08/11 12:28:18 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5)
java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:794)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:833)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:897)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
        at org.spark-project.guava.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:207)
        at org.spark-project.guava.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:252)
        at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1617)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:205)
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

I have disabled the HDFS cache:

```
conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache", True)
```

Note that the exact same script in Scala does not have any issues at all.

Although this is a large job, there is loads of memory available for it. Anyone know what the issue could be?

**UPDATE**

Allocated more memory to JVM.

```
export set JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx6G -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -XX:+UseCompressedOops"
```

Sadly, no improvement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497259/how-to-fix-requested-array-size-exceeds-vm-limit-error-in-java

Comment: Have you tried increasing `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a similar problem with spark-submit and Java, saving an 8GB DataFrame. Docker container with 16-core, 300GB RAM. I haven't resolved the problem yet, but I've come across a couple possible workarounds:

Starting on page 77, [Lightbend](https://deanwampler.github.io/polyglotprogramming/papers/ScalaJVMBigData-SparkLessons.pdf) suggests this is a problem with the shell, using @transient or encapsulating in an object may be a workaround. This doesn't seem to apply in either of our cases.

[DataBricks](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/1140/im-seeing-an-outofmemoryerror-requested-array-size.html) suggests that increasing the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` may help. They suggest changing from the default '200' to '400'. I've tried '800' and '2000' in `spark-defaults.conf` but still get the OOM Error.

[DataBricks](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/1140/im-seeing-an-outofmemoryerror-requested-array-size.html) also suggests calling `DataFrame.repartition(400)` in the code. Or, increase the number of `partitions` as the last parameter to your call to `sc.wholeTextFiles(inputFileDir, partitions)`

The `JAVA_OPTS` suggestions from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497259/) wouldn't apply as `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` is disabled (in Java 8) if heap size is greater than 32GB

**EDIT**

Also tried:

- `spark.default.parallelism=1000` (default is number of cores). Still OOM Error.
- `dataFrame.repartition(1000)` in the code. Still OOM Error.

**Possible Workarounds**

- Using intermediate `RDD<LabeledPoint>` allowed me to create the DataFrame, but the Spark reflection schema doesn't work with MLLib (missing numClasses attribute).

  `DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(List<LabeledPoint>),LabeledPoint.class)`
- Using intermediate JSON file allowed me to create the DataFrame to work with MLLib.

  `saveAsJson(List<Row>/*generated data*/, filename);
  DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json(filename)`