# Spark - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am attempting a groupBy operation on dataframe in Cloudera's Spark (2.1.0) on a 7 node cluster with about 512GB of RAM total. My code is as follows.

```
ndf = ndf.repartition(20000)
by_user_df = ndf.groupBy(ndf.name) \
            .agg(collect_list("file_name")) \
            .withColumnRenamed('collect_list(file_name)', 'file_names')


by_user_df = by_user_df.repartition(20000)    
by_user_df.count()
```

ndf is a dataframe containing 2 columns, a userid and a filename. I am trying to create a list of filenames by userid for passing to CountVectorizer and clustering.

I get the following error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.BufferHolder.grow(BufferHolder.java:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

From what I have read, this is due to allocating an array either bigger than what the VM can handle in contiguous memory or larger than a system maximum for array size. Many of the recommendations are to parallelize more by splitting into more partitions.

I have about 6k users and about 7k total filenames. I have noticed that the executor that dies spends the majority of its time in Garbage Collection.

I have tried the following this far:

1. re-partitioning the ndf dataframe and the resulting dataframe. I have tried up to 60k in the repartition arguments for each.
2. I have set "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions"  in steps up to 20000
3. I have boosted executor memory to  25G
4. Even though the executor that dies does not appear to be the driver, I have boosted driver memory to 25G as well.

As an update to this question: I realized that in this case I am doing a binary clustering over the data so I really need just one of each of the filenames. Changing `collect_list` to `collect_set` left me with the output that I needed and was apparently small enough to run within the given parameters. I'm still going to try to fix the original case.

Comment: When you run spark can you set those --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions and --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions?

Comment: I can. Are there options that you are recommending?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't really understand why you need such a high value of partitions. I don't know how many cores you have on each of the 7 workers but I doubt you need more than 200 partitions (The extremely high amounts of partitions you are using may actually explain why your workers die from Garbage Collection)

Your problem looks like a memory problem within the definitions of the JVM so I see no reason to boost driver or workers memory.

I think what you need is to set the Xss or Xmx or MaxPermSize like explined here: [How to fix "Requested array size exceeds VM limit" error in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497259/how-to-fix-requested-array-size-exceeds-vm-limit-error-in-java)

To do so you need to use --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions and --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions when you run spark.

For Example:

```
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Xss10m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M " --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Xss10m -XX:MaxPermSize=128M "
```

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the partitions, my understanding was that the more partitions, the more the array was spread over multiple JVMs. While none of the workers actually died from garbage collect, you are correct that they did seem to spend a lot of time there.  I had thought that increasing the worker memory would in turn increase the JVM's stack size and permanent storage size but I will  reduce the partitions and try these java options as well.