# memory error in computing the Inverse of a big matrix in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, matrix-inverse, sparklyr

I'm trying to compute the inverse of a 25GB matrix in spark, i'm working in a local mode with a machine of 6GB in memory.
i have found this code: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290485/climbs-lika-spyder 
Its work is based on computing SVD.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors,Vector,Matrix,SingularValueDecomposition,DenseMatrix,DenseVector}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

def computeInverse(X: RowMatrix): DenseMatrix = {
val nCoef = X.numCols.toInt
val svd = X.computeSVD(nCoef, computeU = true)
if (svd.s.size < nCoef) {
sys.error(s"RowMatrix.computeInverse called on singular matrix. }

// Create the inv diagonal matrix from S 
val invS = DenseMatrix.diag(new DenseVector(svd.s.toArray.map(x => math.pow(x,-1))))

// U cannot be a RowMatrix
val U = new DenseMatrix(svd.U.numRows().toInt,svd.U.numCols().toInt,svd.U.rows.collect.flatMap(x => x.toArray))

// If you could make V distributed, then this may be better. However its alreadly local...so maybe this is fine.
val V = svd.V
// inv(X) = V*inv(S)*transpose(U)  --- the U is already transposed.
(V.multiply(invS)).multiply(U) }
```

my problem is when i tried to compute the SVD of a row matrix this error pop-out even when i increased the heap size.

```
scala> computeInverse(result)
18/05/04 23:50:18 WARN RowMatrix: computing svd with k=36704 and  n=36704, please check necessity
18/05/04 23:50:18 WARN RowMatrix: The input data is not directly cached, which may hurt performance if its parent RDDs are also uncached.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: k must be smaller than n in dist-eigs mode but got k=36704 and n=36704.
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeSVD(RowMatrix.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeSVD(RowMatrix.scala:194)
at computeInverse(<console>:34)
... 50 elided
```

so i deacreased K to 20000, however, the error came again indicating heap size problem

```
 scala> val svd = result.computeSVD(20000, computeU = true)
18/05/06 13:18:08 WARN RowMatrix: computing svd with k=20000 and n=36704, please check necessity
18/05/06 13:18:08 WARN RowMatrix: The input data is not directly cached, which may hurt performance if its parent RDDs are also uncached.
18/05/06 13:18:08 WARN ARPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemARPACK
18/05/06 13:18:08 WARN ARPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefARPACK
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.EigenValueDecomposition$.symmetricEigs(EigenValueDecomposition.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeSVD(RowMatrix.scala:268)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeSVD(RowMatrix.scala:194)
... 29 elided
```

is any one have an idea or an alternative solution?
and can i have some explanation how spark allocate the hardware to do such operation

Comment: Why do you think it's a memory problem? It seems like you get : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: k must be smaller than n in dist-eigs mode but got k=36704 and n=36704.

Comment: cause even when i decreased K to a smaler number there steel an error         [18/05/05 19:30:56 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 8)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
]

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: i have edited the first question, i'm appreciating your collaboration, thanks

Comment: Take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144245/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-requested-array-size-exceeds-vm-limit/50157062#50157062